# Imprimir solo un elemento HTML con el evento keyup en un formulario

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Estoy creando un formulario en el cual voy a evaluar si las contraseñas coinciden correctamente. Estoy usando el evento keyup y funciona a 'medias' por que cada vez que las contraseñas no coinciden se vuelve a añadir al DOM el elemento.

```js
$('#buttonContinueSettings').attr("disabled", true);
  
  $('.form-settings').on('keyup', '.vnpass', function(){

    var newContrasena = $(".npass").val();
    var verifyNewContrasena = $('.vnpass').val();

    if (newContrasena == verifyNewContrasena) {
      $('.vnpass').parent().removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
      $('.form-settings').find('span').removeClass('glyphicon-remove').addClass('glyphicon-ok');
      $('#buttonContinueSettings').attr("disabled", false);
    } else {
      $('.vnpass').parent().addClass('has-error has-feedback');
      $('.vnpass').after(`
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove 
        form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        `
      );
      $('.vnpass').tooltip({
        'trigger':'hover',
        'title':'Las contraseñas nuevan tienen que ser las mismas.',
        'placement':'bottom'
      });
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
        <form class="form-settings" action="" method="POST">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">
            Cambiar contraseña
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword1">Contraseña nueva</label>
                      <input type="password" class="form-control npass" name="" placeholder="Contraseña nueva" required>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword1">Verificar contraseña nueva</label>
                      <input type="password" class="form-control vnpass" name="" placeholder="Verificar contraseña nueva" required>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>

              <button type="submit" id="buttonContinueSettings" class="btn btn-info">Continuar</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Cancelar</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Lo único que quiero es que el elemento se imprima solo una vez, ¿Hay algún evento que pueda hacer eso que pido?

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quieres que ocurra en el tercer input? Así como está se tiene que escribir nuevamente la contraseña para validar, en ves de tomar los datos de los dos inputs anteriores y hacer la comparación sin necesidad de un tercer input.

Comment: @Lixus El primer input era para ingresar la contraseña actual que tiene el usuario en la base de datos. El segundo input era para ingresar la nueva contraseña y el tercer input era el que va a validar si está coincide este con el segundo. Ya elimine el primero para no malinterpretar.
Lo único que deseo es que no se añada al DOM el elemento cada vez que pulse una tecla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. La verificación en java script es con 3 iguales === eso lo debes corregir
2. Después de verificar que las contraseñas no coincidan deberías verificar si ya agregaste la clase `'has-error has-feedback'` con el método `.hasClass()` si tiene la clase de error pues retornas y no agregas la clase
3. Ahora cuando ya verificas que las contraseñas son iguales remueves la clase `.removeClass()`